# How to collect code coverage from playwright to Sonar (Angular Project)

Tags: angular, testing, babeljs, playwright, nrwl-nx

seeking help regarding the topic.
There is an Angular project built with nrwl that includes Playwright e2e tests. However, I am unable to extend the existing unit tests (which are Jest based and were set up out-of-the-box) to achieve proper code coverage for Playwright in SonarCloud.

I would be very thankful for any kind of help or references, how can I achieve such a configuration

I tried the solution:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-coverage
but when the is some difference in the source map from angular and v8 code coverage, so conversation failed
Tried this as well:
https://github.com/anishkny/playwright-test-coverage
here my fault I haven't direct access to the babelrc file (because of nrwl monorepo)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two testing modes, unit and e2e, the first step is to standardize the original format of the coverage data.

For example, use `v8` as the data provider for both:

1, unit test:

Install this custom reporter for Jest `npm i jest-monocart-coverage`

```
// jest.config.js
const config = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    coverageReporters: ['none'],
    reporters: [
        ['jest-monocart-coverage', {
            name: 'My Unit Coverage Report',
            reports: [
                ['v8'],
                ['console-summary'],
                ['lcovonly']
            ],
            outputDir: './coverage-reports/unit'
        }]
    ],
};
export default config;
```

There will be a `./coverage-reports/unit/lcov.info` generated for Sonar.

2, e2e test:

Install this custom reporter for Playwright `npm i monocart-reporter`
And collect global coverage report through this [tutorial](https://github.com/cenfun/monocart-reporter?tab=readme-ov-file#global-coverage-report). Note, please use `lcovonly` report to generate `lcov.info` for Sonar too.

3, Upload 2 `lcov.info` to Sonar Cloud.